# How do I use a ListView to show updated data such as voltage?

Tags: android, listview

So I want to display my voltage input I get with my OBD2 adapter. Right now I just have the voltage display as a `textview` in a handler, but I would like to have it so that it shows in a `listview` because it's more convenient when adding more and more data to look over.

Listview Example:

---

### Voltage:                                                                                                      0,0 V

---

### RPM:                                                                                                             0

---

**BTHandler.java**

```
public void run() {
    OBDcmds();

    try {

        ModuleVoltageCommand voltageCommand = new ModuleVoltageCommand();

        while (!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) {
            guiHandler(Constants.VOLTAGE_STATUS, 0, voltageCommand.getFormattedResult());

            try {
                voltageCommand.run(mmInStream, mmOutStream);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {...}
}
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
private Handler mHandler = new Handler() {
    TextView voltageView = null;

    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
        switch (msg.what) {
            case Constants.MESSAGE_STATE_CHANGE:
                switch (msg.arg1) {
                    case BTHandler.STATE_CONNECTED:
                        (...)
                        socView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.socView);
                        break;
                    case (...)
                        break;
                }
                break;
            case Constants.VOLTAGE_STATUS:
                if (msg.obj != null && voltageView != null) {
                    voltageView.setText((String) msg.obj);
                }
                break;
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: create your custom_list layout

Comment: @VivekMishra Sorry, but you have to be more specific

Comment: Instead of handler use listview with adapters. Search for this and you will get lots of tutorial for this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to create a custom layout for the [ListView](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/listview.html) item, create an [ArrayAdapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html), and refer to the custom layout for a listview item within the ArrayAdapter.

Check out these tutorials:

- [Using lists in Android (ListView) - Tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidListView/article.html)
- [Building Custom Android ListViews](https://nickcharlton.net/posts/building-custom-android-listviews.html?xyzallow)
- [Android ListView Custom Adapter and Layout](http://www.survivingwithandroid.com/2012/10/android-listview-custom-adapter-and.html)